# JSON perspective

Tags: javascript, json

Lets say I have a JSON document / JavaScript object that looks like this:

```
var animal = {
  "squirrel": "Squirrels belong to a large family of small or medium-sized rodents called the Sciuridae."
}
```

In JavaScript, this would happen:

```
console.log(animal.squirrel) //Squirrels belong to a large family of small or medium-sized rodents called the Sciuridae
```

Let's say I wanted to add the `rank` object in:

```
var animal = {
  "squirrel": {   
    "rank": {
      "Kingdom": "Animalia",
      "Phylum": "Chordata",
      "Class": "Mammalia",
      "Order": "Rodentia",
      "Suborder": "Sciuromorpha",
      "Family": "Sciuridae"
    }
  }
}
```

The rank would be accessible like so:

```
animal.squirrel.rank
```

But I still want the top-level of the `animal.squirrel` object to be a string containing the sentence above.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible in JSON. In JavaScript, however, there are a few things you can do. You can provide a `toString` method to be used when the object is converted to a string:

```
var animal = {
  "squirrel": {   
    "rank": {
      "Kingdom": "Animalia",
      "Phylum": "Chordata",
      "Class": "Mammalia",
      "Order": "Rodentia",
      "Suborder": "Sciuromorpha",
      "Family": "Sciuridae"
    },
    toString: function() {
      return "Squirrels belong to a large family of small or medium-sized rodents called the Sciuridae.";
    }
  }
};
```

You can also use a `String` object:

```
var animal = {
    squirrel: new String("Squirrels belong to a large family of small or medium-sized rodents called the Sciuridae.")
};

animal.squirrel.rank = {
    "Kingdom": "Animalia",
    "Phylum": "Chordata",
    "Class": "Mammalia",
    "Order": "Rodentia",
    "Suborder": "Sciuromorpha",
    "Family": "Sciuridae"
};
```

The latter acts more like a string, but it uses a `String` object, which can be frustrating at times and is usually bad practice.

Comment: Oh, you were 1 minute faster than me! @ThomasReggi You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/JcTCx/

Answer (score 1):

As the others said, this isn't possible in any object context, so you'll need to handle everything as accessible parts *on/in* the object.

```
var animal = {
  "squirrel": {
    "info": "Squirrels belong to a large family of small or medium-sized rodents called the Sciuridae.",
    "rank": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

And, I suppose unrelated, you could setup quick accessors for commonalities.

```
function getAnimalInfo(animalName) {
  if (!animal[animalName]) return "No info for: " + animalName;

  return animal[animalName].info;
}
```

So,

```
console.log(getAnimalInfo("squirrel")); //Squirrels belong to a large family of small or medium-sized rodents called the Sciuridae
```

Comment: I like this. Something about it is clean. Still wish I could use `animal.squirrel` though.